# BitLocker in Windows 7 Ultimate decryption of external HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bitlocker

I have locked my external hard disc using [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/bitlocker).  After formatting my computer I have lost all keys to open my external hard disc.  Is there any way to unlock the external drive.

Comment: If there was a way, how safe would BitLocker be?

Comment: If you don't have the keys to the data then the data is lost.  Why don't you have a backup of your keys?

Answer (score 1):

The company [Passware allows you to retrieve lost passwords (recover from bitlocker)](http://www.lostpassword.com/kit-forensic.htm) but you will need to review each piece of software to see which is best. Please note, this isn't cheap!